# What is the best way to switch AWSCredentialsProviders?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I am writing a Java application that users Spring for dependency injection and AWS for various services. I will be deploying the application to EC2. The issue I am having is setting the AWS credentials in a secure way during development/deployment. Because the service is running on EC2, I would like to use the [InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html) in production. However, these credentials are not available during development.

Almost all the AWS clients are currently injected using Spring. Here is an example using DynamoDB:

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "my.dynamoDB")
    public DynamoDB dynamoDB() {
        return DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(
            new AWSCredentialsProvider() /* What should go here? */));

    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a separate bean that returns a credentials provider. Within that method switch between the two credential sources based on stage or host type.

```
/** 
 * @return: an AWSCredentialsProvider appropriate for the stage. 
 */
@Bean
public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
    if(isProd() /* define what this means in your configuration code */) {
        return new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()
    } else {
        return new AWSCredentialsProvider()
    }
}
```